# Как множественное применение mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ... влияет на скорость базы?

Tags: php, mysql

у меня на странице в коде 4 раза применяется... mysql_query("SELECT * FROM...

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE `id`='$rrrr'",$db);    
$result4 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `aaaa`, `link` WHERE `link`.`article_id`='$page' AND `link`.`tags_id`=`tags`.`id`",$db);    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE `id`='$rrrrr'",$db);    
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE `id`='$rrrrr'",$db);
```

грамотно ли так писать код? Не будет ли этот код тормозить загрузку страницы при большом посещении?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для базы данных такие запросы незначительны. В вашей ситуации такой миникод тоже не опасен. Но хочу выйти с обращением ко всем начинающим писарям на PHP,не примите это как критику, но возьмите на вооружение! Да этот язык написания сценариев демократичен, можно вносить дилетантские  штучки, можно даже иногда ошибаться... НО! Со временем, по мере прибавления знаний, код будет увеличиваться и усложнятся, запоминать станет труднее и вот тогда помимо проблем с головной болью у вас появятся проблемы со скоростью работы кода, проблемы с безопасностью.
 Есть стиль написания, который придумали разработчики PHP называется "Zend" советую почитать. Запомните! У хорошего программиста должен быть хороший код!

Comment: Zend - любитель ООП. Лично я еще не встретил ни одного веб-проекта с бюджетом до 1 миллиона рублей, в котором ООП хоть чем-то оправдан.

Comment: Считать, что Zend это только ООП - глубокое заблуждение. Если ты имеешь богатый опыт в веб-проектах может посоветуешь свои источники?!

Comment: Я и не говорил слово "только".

Answer (score 2):

Проблемы:

1) Названия переменных ( `$result, $rrrrr` ), таблиц ( `aaaa, types, link` ) крайне "информативны"

2) Зачем дважды один и тот-же запрос?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE id='$rrrrr'",$db);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM types WHERE id='$rrrrr'",$db);
```

В зависимости от реальной необходимости, можно сделать так:

```
$query_types = mysql_query(
  "SELECT * FROM types WHERE id in ( '$rrrr', '$rrrrr')", $db
);
```

Comment: тут синтаксис не важен.. я просто хочу теоретически узнать...когда вот так 4 раза на  странице СЕЛЕКТ ФРОМ.... используешь сильно ли это будет тормозить базу? так вообще по-человечески писать можно?

Comment: На php как не пиши - все равно обзовут говнокодом....)
Лично я считаю, что нужно искать наименьшее зло из числа запросов и количестве потребляемой памяти. Т.е. все зависит от конкретной ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Базе данных сайта приходится хранить немало различных сведений и при генерации текущей страницы надо выбирать из разных таблиц: название, автора и контент этой страницы; выбрать нужный шаблон; не забыть комментарии к странице; случайную цитату; случайные фото на странице; обратиться к счетчику посещений; показать TOP10 популярных страниц; показать сведения об текущем пользователе и многое другое приходится брать из разных таблиц при динамическом составлении страницы.